# save optional parameter of command

Tags: macros

I want to have a command that by default uses a default string and if supplied the optional parameter. I tried it using let, but that gives strange results

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\standardstring}{standard}
\newcommand{\printresult}[1][\standardstring]{%
    \let\printstring#1
    \printstring
}

\begin{document}   
\printresult

\printresult[abc]
\end{document}
```

This results in

```
standard
bc a
```

Comment: Do you plan that `\standardstring` has a fixed value for the whole LaTeX run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, the assignment is:

```
\let\printstring\standardstring␣
```

The non-standard case:

```
\let\printstring abc␣
```

In both cases the line contains a space by the end of line. In the latter case
the assignment is `\let\printstring=a`. Then `bc` and the space from the end of line is set, finally `\printstring` follows.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\standardstring}{standard}
\newcommand{\printresult}[1][\standardstring]{%
    \def\printstring{#1}%
    \printstring
}

\begin{document}
\printresult

\printresult[abc]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand\standardstring{standard}
\newcommand{\printresult}[1][\standardstring]{%
  \edef\standardstring{#1}#1}

\begin{document}   
\printresult

\printresult[abc]

\printresult
\end{document}
```